# 15 Un-written BrahmaLokas in Dhammacakkapavattana sutta

Tags: sutras

I was wondering about Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta. All i know is that when buddha turned the dhamma wheel for the first time, all of the residents of Devalokas and The Rupa-Brahmalokas came and claps their hands.

There's this 1 phrase which sounds:
"Brahmakayika deva saddamanussavesum"

As for Brahmakayika is the lowest of brahmaloka [1st Jhana Realm]. I don't think brahmakayika could represent all of the rupa-brahmalokas [Inculiding 1st 2nd 3rd and 4th Jhana Realms]

The Question is, why other rupa-brahmalokas name were not included or unwritten in the text, did they forget to write it or is there any missing text during that time?

Thank you,
LomX

Answer (score 2):

Footnote 200 on page 59 of [Piya Tan's translation](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.1-Dhammacakka-Pavattana-S-s56.11-piya.pdf) says,

> It is interesting and important to note that the list of exulting devas stops here with the Brahmās of the 1st dhyana.
>   The reason for this is that, as there is still some level of mentation here—by way of initial and sustained applications
>   (vitakka,vicāra)—these Brahmās are still in contact with the sense-world. In the realms beyond the 1st dhyana,
>   thought-process as we know it ceases completely so that these beings enjoy the glory of their meditative state as
>   pure light or profound peace for as long as their karma fuels it. See Bhava Ss 1-2 (A 3.76-77), SD 23.13 (3).

Answer (score 1):

The Buddhists suttas describe thirty-one distinct "planes" or "realms" of existence into which beings can be reborn during this long wandering through samsara life cycle. Check [The Thirty-one Planes of Existence](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html). Also  [**THIS**](https://dhammawiki.com/index.php?title=31_planes_of_existence), and [**THIS**](http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/The_Buddhist_universe_consists_of_thirty-one_planes_of_existence), and [**THIS**](http://www.lawsofthenature.com/PlanesOfExistence.aspx)

They consist of four planes of the Immaterial (formless) Brahma Realm (arupa-loka); sixteen planes of the Fine Material Brahma Realm(rupa-loka); and eleven planes of the Sensuous Realm(kama-loka). A rough rule is that the bodies are dense in the lower realms and lighter and fine in the higher realms

In the Rupa Brahma Realm they have only three sense faculties of eyes, ears, and the mind (only two physical senses of eyes and ears). The fine bodies of the “rupa brahmas have no hands. Their bodies are much less dense than even those of the devas. And even devas are unable to see the fine bodies of the “rupa brahmas“, i.e., those brahmas in the rupa lokas.

The inhabitants of Immaterial (formless) Brahma realms are possessed entirely of mind. Having no physical body, they are unable to hear Dhamma teachings. Those of the arupa loka, the “arupa brahmas” who have only the mind do not even have a desire for sights and sounds. Mind pleasures are enough for them, and the presence of matter is minimal in the arupa loka.

Answer (score 0):

[AN 4.123](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.123.than.html) and MN 1 describe the *Abhassara*, *Subhakinha* and *Vehapphala* devas as the state of *attachment* (*upadana*), *self-becoming* (*bhava*) or *sakkaya* (*self-identifying*) in respect to the 2nd, 3rd & 4th jhanas, which, due to attachment, all have hell as the destination.

As described in [MN 49](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.049.than.html) and DN 11, the Brahma gods generally do not rejoice in the Buddha-Dhamma of impermanence, not-self & the cessation of being (*bhava*), which is why they are not free from *dukkha* & wind up in hell.